# Create one single instance per tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, java-threads

I have a class named as Test which is printing number from 1 to 100 in a delay of 10 seconds. If i open it from command prompt and try to run it will start printing the data. If i am opening second command prompt and run this program it will work. But i want to restrict that it should run from only single command prompt. How can we do that.

This is my code

```
public class ThreadDelay{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test t1= new Test();
        t1.start();


    }

}
class Test extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            System.out.println("Value of i ===:"+i);
            Thread t=new Thread();
            try {
                t.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your title and text conflict. Which is it, Tomcat or command line?

Comment: So like only one instance of that program can run on each device? I would just do it a lame way and open a local `Socket` and If there is one already open then you know the program is running elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the singleton pattern. The easiest implementation consists of a private constructor and a field to hold its result, and a static accessor method with a name like `getInstance()`.

The private field can be assigned from within a static initializer block or, more simply, using an initializer. The `getInstance()` method (which must be public) then simply returns this instance,

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    /**
     * A private Constructor prevents any other class from
     * instantiating.
     */
    private Singleton() {
        // nothing to do this time
    }

    /**
     * The Static initializer constructs the instance at class
     * loading time; this is to simulate a more involved
     * construction process (it it were really simple, you'd just
     * use an initializer)
     */
    static {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }

    /** Static 'instance' method */
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // other methods protected by singleton-ness would be here...
    /** A simple demo method */
    public String demoMethod() {
        return "demo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want only `single instance` of `thread` to be created.
If you declare your thread as an instance variable and static then it will work for you.

```
public class ThreadDelay {
    static Thread t;
    ...
```

Write just `t=new Thread();` inside run block.

---

Update: You might want to run your class on Tomcat application server.
You would also need to use `Singleton class` to handle the creation of multiple `Thread class` objects. (In case of opening tens of command prompt windows at once).